# What is the difference between Handler implementation with WeakReference and without it?

Tags: android

I making Service with Handler and I need Handler to use some Service methods. As Handler must be `static`, I can access Service methods without Service reference in Handler.

So I did this way:

```
private static class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
    MyService service;

    public ServiceHandler(MyService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        ...
    }
}
```

But also found that this is the right way to do the job:

```
private static class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
    private final WeakReference<MyService> mMyService;

    public ServiceHandler(MyService service) {
        mMyService = new WeakReference<MyService>(service);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        MyService service = mMyService.get();
        ...
    }
}
```

What is the difference in this two ways to use Service in Handler?

Comment: And why must your Handler be a static inner class if it needs a reference to the service?

Comment: @DavidWasser because if Handler isn't static, I get warning about memory leaks.

Comment: Just make sure you set the Handler variable to null in `onDestroy()` of the service and you can ignore the warning.

Comment: Where are you getting a warning about memory leaks? Please post that code

Comment: @DavidWasser i got warnings in this line `private class ServiceHandler extends Handler { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first code example sets a member variable to a reference of the calling `Service` (which I assume is the outer class of this inner class). This is exactly the same as if you had removed the `static` keyword for the inner class, because now the inner class is holding a reference to an instance of the `Service` class (which is what you are usually trying to avoid when you use the `static` keyword).

The second code example uses a weak reference, which means that the garbage collector can clean up (destroy) the instance of the `Service` class, even though you are holding a reference to it in your Handler. If that occurs, the call to `mMyService.get()` will return null, so you had better check for that in your code.

In practice, there are no differences between these 2 code examples since you won't be using the `Handler` once the `Service` has been destroyed.